# Image in the Canvas Immediately Disappears after drawimage

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I've been using an input type="file" to browse an image and draw it in a canvas. Below is my code:

HTML Code:

```
<img id="img_registrar_signature" src="" alt="ID Photo" hidden />
<canvas id='myid_registrar_signature' width='500' height='100'></canvas>
<input type="file" id="myid_registrar_signature_upload" onChange="readURL(this);" />
```

Javascript Code:

```
function myid_open_file_dialog(elemId)
{
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
    if(elem && document.createEvent) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
        elem.dispatchEvent(evt);       
    }       
}

$("#myid_registrar_signature_upload").click(function (event) {
    $("#myid_registrar_signature_upload").val("");
    myid_open_file_dialog('myid_registrar_signature_upload');                   
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var image  = new Image();            
        reader.onload = function (e){                  
            image.src = e.target.result;
            $('#img_registrar_signature')
                .attr('src', e.target.result);                      

            image.onload = function() {
                var canvas= document.getElementById("myid_registrar_signature");
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                img_registrar = document.getElementById("img_registrar_signature");
                context.drawImage(this,0,0, this.width, this.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);                                                     
            }                

        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);        
    }
}
```

My problem is as I browse an image and display it to my canvas, the image gets loaded and immediately disappears. It seems it was automatically cleared. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. You do have a typo there though, the close tag for canvas is missing a backslash, ie. `</canvas>`. Any errors in console? Any events causing canvas to resize?

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg Thanks Ken, the console throws no error but when I tried executing the code line by line, the image doesn't disappear. Where am I missing?

Comment: @NK Thanks for giving me an idea. How to make it not-recursive? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a recursion problem in this part:

```
$("#myid_registrar_signature_upload").click(function (event) {
    $("#myid_registrar_signature_upload").val("");
    myid_open_file_dialog('myid_registrar_signature_upload');                   
});
```

This will generate a click which in turn calls the same method until it runs out of stack (browser aborts).

Commenting out the following line will make it work, but you need to find a way around depending on what you try to achieve (there shouldn't be any need to invoke a click event for the button you'll click anyway.. :) ):

```
$("#myid_registrar_signature_upload").click(function (event) {
    $("#myid_registrar_signature_upload").val("");
    //myid_open_file_dialog('myid_registrar_signature_upload');                   
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/add3zx91/)**

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the `myid_open_file_dialog` function as it is (I don't know whether it is used somewhere).

```js
function myid_open_file_dialog(elemId)
{
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
    if(elem && document.createEvent) {
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
        elem.dispatchEvent(evt);       
    }       
}

$("#myid_registrar_signature_upload").click(function (event) {
    if(event.which) {
        $("#myid_registrar_signature_upload").val("");
        myid_open_file_dialog('myid_registrar_signature_upload');
    }
    event.preventDefault();
});

function readURL(input) {debugger;
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var image  = new Image();            
        reader.onload = function (e){                  
            image.src = e.target.result;
            $('#img_registrar_signature')
                .attr('src', e.target.result);                      

            image.onload = function() {
                var canvas= document.getElementById("myid_registrar_signature");
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                img_registrar = document.getElementById("img_registrar_signature");
                context.drawImage(this,0,0, this.width, this.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);                                                     
            }                

        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);        
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img_registrar_signature" src="" alt="ID Photo" hidden />
<canvas id='myid_registrar_signature' width='500' height='100'></canvas>
<input type="file" id="myid_registrar_signature_upload" onchange="readURL(this);" />
```